# SQL - how to select values which aren't 0, but may be NULL?

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL table, I have some rows with `status` = NULL and some with `status` = 0

When selecting them in a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `status` != 0
```

This ignores both `0` and `NULL` values.

How can I ignore ONLY `0` values?

Comment: NULL is not the same as 'NOT something' -- it means "not known" so therefore the boolaen expression fails.  The answer is in your question: `WHERE status != 0 OR status IS NULL`

Comment: `status` is a number field or a text field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `is null` predicate:

if `status` is a numeric field:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `status` != 0
OR `status` IS NULL
```

if `status` is a text field:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `status` != '0'
OR `status` IS NULL
```

This works because `NULL != 0` evaluates as `NULL` and `NULL OR TRUE` evaluates as `TRUE`. Rows whose inclusion condition evaluates to `NULL` are rejected.

Comment: Wouldn't you need `IS NULL` first if `!=0` ignores the nulls (according to OP)?

Comment: @njk I assumed `status` was a numeric field. Removed the assumption.

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios not really. `null OR true` is true.

Comment: @njk note that the string `'null'` cast to a number produces a zero and is rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't try it, but maybe this?

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `status` IS NULL OR `status` != 0
```

Comment: Note the [fiddle by NJK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/641e2/4). This fails if ``status`` is a string.

Comment: Ah. I didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your sqlfiddle, it appears `status` is a text type, so this is what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE status IS NULL
OR status != '0'
```

Comment: Now it has the same problem as mine. It rejects any non-empty text.

Comment: @JanDvorak That fiddle isn't my query - notice the quotes around my `0`. Here's my fiddle working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/641e2/15

Comment: Sorry. Do you think I've cleaned the confusion in my own answer? It's conditionally correct _without_ the quotes as well.

Comment: @JanDvorak I've plus oned you, but do add a comment about how normal comparisons with nulls are always false and that's why you need the `is null` bit added

Comment: Comparison with `null` is not `false`. It's `null`.

Comment: I did. Do you think I've added enough?

Comment: @JanDvorak yes it is false when comparing with null, ie `null = null` is false and further `null != anything` is also false. You must use `is null` to get a hit on a null - it's defined like that in the SQL language. I think you've said enough, (but I would have said it differently)

Comment: I believe `null = null` is `null`, not `false`. The difference is that `not null` is `null` (falsy), while `not false` in `true`(truthy)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude them both:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE COALESCE(status,0)  <> 0
    ;
```

Comment: Doesn't this make indexing on `status` useless?

Comment: @Jan: Indexes.  A function call would have to be executed -- on each row -- before its value is known.  This practically forces a table scan, meaning the index i may have put on this column to speed up the query, now no longer does its job.  Unless MySQL is a lot smarter than i fear it is, anyway.

Comment: It is not necessarily a function call. Postgres evaluates it inline, just as it were written as `where status NOT IS NULL AND status <> 0)`

Comment: @cHao can you add an index on an expression? That would be cool.

Comment: @Jan: I doubt it.  Perhaps if it were a computed column...but does MySQL even have those?

Comment: Indexes are not relevant here. Evaluation of a nullable expression is comparable to a non-nullable column. (BTW: postgresql supports indexes on expressions and even on functions, but that's not relevant here)

Comment: @cHao note that not indexing may kill performance, but will leave correctness unscathed.

Comment: @Jan: Not if "correct" includes "executes in a reasonable amount of time".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [null-safe equals operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)...

```
SELECT status
FROM mytable
WHERE not (status <=> 0);
```

It considers `null` as just another value.  `0 <=> null` is false, as opposed to the `null` you get with normal comparisons.

As with the other answers here, quote the 0 if your `status` column happens to be a (var)char type.